# If $a,b \in G$ and $ab=ba$, prove $ (ab)^{|a||b|}=e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need help with "Show that the above may be false if $ab\neq ba$".

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What are |a| and |b| representing here?  That's not really standard group notation...

Comment: Even better $(ab)^{\mathrm{lcm}(|a|,|b|)}=e$.

Comment: |a| and |b| represent the order of a and b, respectivly

Comment: Is this a question involving groups?  If so, the group-theory tag might come as appropriate.

Comment: Interesting: the question is explicitely NOT the question in the title.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Show $(ab)^k = a^kb^k$ for all $k$...

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about proving the converse (namely, that it doesn't necessarily hold if $a$ and $b$ don't commute), here's a different hint: $ab\neq ba$ (trivially) implies that the group must be non-commutative.  What are some examples of small non-commutative groups that you know?

Hint part 2: try choosing $a$ and $b$ both as elements of order 2 in one of these groups.  If you can find two elements that don't commute with each other, then you automatically have $(ab)^2\neq e$ (can you see why?  Remember that we've picked them such that $a^{-1}=a$ and $b^{-1}=b$) and it should be easy to find a case where you also have $(ab)^4\neq e$.

Comment: The permutation S3... I'm just confused on how to show the order of each a and b.

Comment: There are a couple of ways; (1) you can simply compute powers of each until you find the identity.  (2) If you understand what a permutation *represents*, then from the cycle structure you should easily be able to read off the order.  (For instance, what is the order of the permutation $(1\ 3)$ in $S_3$?)